# Debugging C# app from other computer

Tags: c#, debugging, remote-debugging

I know there is a lot of topics about it, but i didnt find help in there.

I have a C# app that works like a charm for me, but not for other clients, and exceptions says nothing about it, because it works for me. 
So I would like to look inside a code of opened app on other client, that doesnt have Visual Studio. 
I found something like Remote Debuggger, and it connects, it debugs but if i have an exception, code looks like this:

```
6E93BE84  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],ecx  
6E93BE86  call        6E93D430 
6E93BE8B  pop         ecx  
6E93BE8C  pop         ebx  
6E93BE8D  pop         esi  
6E93BE8E  pop         edi
```

I am not a pro, I do not read yet such things :D
Is there possibility to debug a real code with breakpoints etc?

Realy thank you for all tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with remote debugging when you have the PDB and source code files from the moment you made that application for that client. More information can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bt727f1t(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Yeah, problem solved. All is needed to change debug folder other client. Works like a charm